# Properly Importing Tensorflow and Keras in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, import, pycharm

I have the latest Tensorflow installed. I want to use it with PyCharm, but I encountered an  issue. When I import like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
```

Pycharm doesn't recognize Keras and all the layers and it underlines them in red. If I run this in Python, it runs perfectly. However, if I import like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
```

Everything suddenly works and there are no errors. What is the difference between `tensorflow.keras.layers` and `tensorflow.python.keras.layers`?

Also, `tensorflow.python.keras.layers` doesn't have `BatchNormalization` isn't there. This is not only red in PyCharm but also throws an import error in Python.

[image]

## Update

***Note: This code runs perfectly fine. The problem is simply with the IDE incorrectly detecting it. As a result, I get extremely poor or no autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, etc. for Tensorflow methods.***

The problem still persists. I am the latest Pycharm Professional version(2022.2.1). I have Python 3.10.4 with Anaconda and Poetry. I currently have Tensorflow 2.9.1 installed.

Comment: Which python version are you using? These lines of code do not show any error when I tried executing using TensorFlow 2.7, 2.8.2 and 2.9.1. Could you please try again and let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: I updated the information for the question above.